# What does import {} do?

Tags: solidity, import

For example,

> import { FlashLoanReceiverBase } from "./FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol";

FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol is here:
https://github.com/aave/aave-protocol/blob/master/contracts/flashloan/base/FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol

Seems not much different from:

> import ./FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol

at a glance.

Answer (score 1):

There si a small difference btweetn them.

```
import { FlashLoanReceiverBase } from "./FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol"
```

This imports just the `FlashLoanReceiverBase` contract from FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol file.

```
import ./FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol
```

This imports all contracts from the file. In most cases, it wouldn't matter which one you use, because the compiler will figure out what contracts are being used and ignore the others, the compiled code will be the same.